# How to get around a problem with \usetikzlibrary{babel}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, programming

I am currently working on an update of tkz-euclide and new documentation but I just met the following problem. If I compile this code with pdflatex or lualatex and pgf 2.1 (The library babel does not exist with pgf 2.1) then the code compiles fine but with 3.0 pgf I must comment on the call `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` (pgf doc gives **so I recommend to always load this library by saying \usetikzlibrary{babel}**).  I'd like to know where the error occurred. Especially I would like to work around this problem.

With `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` I get the error
Latex Error: ./untitled 2.tex:46 Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \tkz@line@start

Bug in babel, bug in `tikzlibrary{babel}` bug in my code. I would like to keep 
`\usetikzlibrary{babel}` but to avoid the error.

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
    tkzdrawline/.cd,
    start/.code         =  {\gdef\tkz@line@start{#1}},%
    end/.code           =  {\gdef\tkz@line@end{#1}},%
    start style/.code   =  {\tikzset{tkzstartstyle/.style={#1}}},%
    end style/.code     =  {\tikzset{tkzendstyle/.style={#1}}},%
   /tkzdrawline/.unknown/.code ={\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname\pgfkeysalso{%
                         \searchname/.try=#1,/tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1}}} 
%<--------------------------------------------------------------–>
%                              Draw line
%<--------------------------------------------------------------–>
\pgfkeys{tkzdrawline/.cd,
start/.code       =  {\def\tkz@line@start{#1}},%
end/.code         =  {\def\tkz@line@end{#1}},
start style/.code =  {\tikzset{tkzstartstyle/.style={#1}}},
end style/.code   =  {\tikzset{tkzendstyle/.style={#1}}},  
/tkzdrawline/.unknown/.code   = {\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                                 \pgfkeysalso{\searchname/.try=#1,
                                /tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1}}}%       
 %<--------------------------------------------------------------–>
 \def\tkzDrawLine{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@DrawLine}{%
                                  \tkz@DrawLine[]}}% 
 \def\tkz@DrawLine[#1](#2,#3){%
 \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{tkzdrawline/.cd,start = {}, end = {}, start style={}, end style={},}
  \pgfqkeys{/tkzdrawline}{#1}
  \draw[ /tkzdrawline/.cd,#1] (#2) to%
    node [at start,left,/tkzdrawline/.cd,tkzstartstyle] {\tkz@line@start}%
    node [at end,right,/tkzdrawline/.cd,tkzendstyle] {\tkz@line@end} (#3);
 \endgroup
 }% 
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (A) at (0,1) {}; 
     \node (B) at (5,2) {}; 
     \tkzDrawLine[end = {$\alpha$}](A,B)    
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `babel` TikZ library invokes two keys `handle active characters in code` and `handle active characters in nodes`.  The latter controls how node contents are parsed.  The crucial code is:

```
\def\tikz@collect@arg#1{%
  \iftikz@handle@active@nodes%
    \iftikz@collect@pic%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@collected@onpath\expandafter{\tikz@collected@onpath{#1}}%
    \else%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@collected@onpath\expandafter{\tikz@collected@onpath{\scantokens{#1}}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@collected@onpath\expandafter{\tikz@collected@onpath{#1}}%
  \fi%
  \tikz@collect@cont%
}
```

Did you spot it?  It's that `\scantokens` in the inner `\else` branch.  This means that the contents of the node will be rescanned and so the `\makeatletter` no longer applies.  Thus when `\tkz@line@start` is invoked, the tokens are rescanned meaning that it is `\tkz @ l i n e @ s t a r t` (using spaces to separate tokens).

Exactly how to surmount this depends on how deep this gets in your code.  If this is a typical example, you could just use `\csname tkz@line@start\endcsname`.  Another solution, which is a bit more elegant in my mind, is to use the `node contents` key.  This *doesn't* seem to get hit by the `\scantokens` (I guess because the `node contents` are more likely to be used in styles than in bare text).  (Slightly oddly, I seem to still need the empty braces after the second `node` when I do that.)

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298177/86}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
    tkzdrawline/.cd,
    start/.code         =  {\gdef\tkz@line@start{#1}},%
    end/.code           =  {\gdef\tkz@line@end{#1}},%
    start style/.code   =  {\tikzset{tkzstartstyle/.style={#1}}},%
    end style/.code     =  {\tikzset{tkzendstyle/.style={#1}}},%
   /tkzdrawline/.unknown/.code ={\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname\pgfkeysalso{%
                         \searchname/.try=#1,/tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1}}} 
%<--------------------------------------------------------------–>
%                              Draw line
%<--------------------------------------------------------------–>
\pgfkeys{tkzdrawline/.cd,
start/.code       =  {\def\tkz@line@start{#1}},%
end/.code         =  {\def\tkz@line@end{#1}},
start style/.code =  {\tikzset{tkzstartstyle/.style={#1}}},
end style/.code   =  {\tikzset{tkzendstyle/.style={#1}}},  
/tkzdrawline/.unknown/.code   = {\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                                 \pgfkeysalso{\searchname/.try=#1,
                                /tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1}}}%       
 %<--------------------------------------------------------------–>
 \def\tkzDrawLine{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@DrawLine}{%
                                  \tkz@DrawLine[]}}% 
  \def\tkz@DrawLine[#1](#2,#3){%
 \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{tkzdrawline/.cd,start = {}, end = {}, start style={}, end style={},}
  \pgfqkeys{/tkzdrawline}{#1}
  \draw[ /tkzdrawline/.cd,#1] (#2) to%
    node [at start,left,/tkzdrawline/.cd,tkzstartstyle,node contents={\tkz@line@start}]%
    node [at end,right,/tkzdrawline/.cd,tkzendstyle,node contents={\tkz@line@end}] {} (#3);
 \endgroup
 }% 
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (A) at (0,1) {}; 
     \node (B) at (5,2) {}; 
     \tkzDrawLine[end = {$\alpha$}, start={$\beta$}](A,B)    
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: TkZ Euclide with line]

Comment: Thanks for your fine explanation! I had not seen or noticed this `scantokens`