# Bug with tkz-tab and usetikzlibrary{babel}

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-tab

I've been having weird mistakes for a while with my packages. Here's one I don't understand.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \tkzTabInit[deltacl=1,espcl=8]%
     {$x$/1,Signe\\ de $\dfrac{1}{x}$/1.5/1.5,Variation\\ de $\ln$/2}%
     {$0$,$+\infty$}%
     \tkzTabLine[help]{,,}%
  \tkzTabVar{D-/ $-\infty$,  +/$+\infty$}
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

With `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` I get an error:
 Undefined control sequence.
`l.1 \footnotesize Z\thetkz
                        @cnt@impair \thetkz@cnt@lg`

This line is in `tkz-tab` in the macro `\tkzTabLine`.

```
\newcommand*{\tkzTabLine}[2][]{%
 %\makeatletter 
 \setkeys[TAB]{TL}{#1}%   
 \setcounter{tkz@cnt@lg}{\thetkz@cnt@line}%
 \stepcounter{tkz@cnt@line}%
 \setcounter{tkz@cnt@lgnext}{\thetkz@cnt@line}%
 \setcounter{tkz@cnt@cl}{1}%
 \setcounter{tkz@cnt@pair}{1}%
 \setcounter{tkz@cnt@impair}{1}%
 \ifTAB@TL@help% 
 \foreach \x in {#2}
   {
   \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{tkz@cnt@cl}}}{%
   \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg) --%
           node[draw,inner sep =1pt,midway,fill=yellow]%
            {\footnotesize Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg}%
```

Without the library `babel` I can compile my doc but with the library three examples with `\tkzTabLine` give that same mistake.

If I want to use the library I need to use `\makeatletter` in the definition of the macro.

Why this error ?

Comment: The babel library forces the node text to be rescanned with the current catcode (it uses \scantokens) and that means that all @ inside the node text have catcode letter and so fail. Either use \csname yourcommand@withat\endcsname everywhere, or ensure that @ has catcode letter when the node are processed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I’m stupid ! I asked the same question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298177/how-to-get-around-a-problem-with-usetikzlibrarybabel